# SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR: null value in column

Tags: php, database, postgresql

I am building an application with postgres as my preferred database. I have a users table and in the process of saving into it, I got the error below:

> SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR:  null value in column \"verification_code\" violates not-null constraint\nDETAIL:  Failing row contains (825, 2348035442578, S-LF79a_O3ELcNc0TQmLOjy5No0KScjT, $2y$13$tPS82tr5pH2CHfNiZ9OSKOmE/z8iXOpc0PQ0uGWmeQYXtMX9AguBq, null, oyedele.phemy@gmail.com, null, 0, 11, 2020-04-25 13:54:32, 2020-04-25 13:54:32, null, null, null, null).\nThe SQL being executed was: INSERT INTO \"users\" (\"username\", \"auth_key\", \"password_hash\", \"email\", \"isActivated\", \"status\", \"created_at\", \"updated_at\") VALUES ('2348035442578', 'S-LF79a_O3ELcNc0TQmLOjy5No0KScjT', '$2y$13$tPS82tr5pH2CHfNiZ9OSKOmE/z8iXOpc0PQ0uGWmeQYXtMX9AguBq', 'oyedele.phemy@gmail.com', 0, 11, NOW(), NOW()) RETURNING \"id\"

Here is the table structure:

```
                                               Table "public.users"
        Column        |              Type              | Collation | Nullable |              Default
----------------------+--------------------------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------------------
 id                   | integer                        |           | not null | nextval('users_id_seq'::regclass)
 username             | character varying(255)         |           | not null |
 auth_key             | character varying(32)          |           | not null |
 password_hash        | character varying(255)         |           | not null |
 password_reset_token | character varying(255)         |           |          |
 email                | character varying(255)         |           | not null |
 verification_code    | character varying(255)         |           | not null |
 isActivated          | smallint                       |           | not null | 0
 status               | smallint                       |           | not null | 10
 created_at           | timestamp(0) without time zone |           | not null |
 updated_at           | timestamp(0) without time zone |           | not null |
 profile_picture      | character varying(55)          |           |          |
 filename             | character varying(70)          |           |          |
 pin_no               | integer                        |           |          |
 last_login_date      | date                           |           |          |
```

Where do you think I should check for correction or what exactly am I not doing right?

Comment: The error message is quite clear. You are trying to insert a `null` value in column `verification_code`, which is defined as `not null` . Either make the column nullable so it allows `null` values, or provide a non `null` value for `insert`.

Comment: Thanks. I carefully looked at it and realized that it has already been added to my model but then went ahead to declare that same field as a variable which was causing the omission from the list of fields to be saved hence the "Not NULL violation" error. Thanks for the insight